# How to newly wire furnace condensate pump that contains a safety switch?

Tags: furnace, pump, condensate

I would like to replace my current Little Giant furnace condensate pump that has no safety switch with the Little Giant VCMA-15ULS, 65 GPH Automatic Condensate Removal Pump w/ Safety Switch - SKU 554405. The pump drains Carrier central A/C and Carrier furnace humidifier. Can someone please provide and/or refer me to explicit wiring instructions for installing this pump and enabling it to shut down the Central A/C and only the humidifier, not the furnace, in case of pump failure?

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring diagram and actual wiring for your furnace/air-handler?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I usually interrupt the Compressor’s signal to turn on. This will prevent additional moisture from being generated. Other ways are to add that safety inline (series) with a fan safety switch. 
I do not like pump based safety’s my preferred method is leak detection tape or sensors, because when the pump fails and it will, the separate sensor still works and not need to be replaced.